# Low idle and stall

Tags: toyota, starting, stall, camry

Why does my car idle low and sometimes die?
I have a 2001 Toyota Camry and sometimes when I go to start it the car doesn't want to stay started and will die.It will only stay started after I rev the engine a few times. It doesn't die at any other time then other when I start it and it's only occasionally not every time. It also seems to have just started with the cold weather. I have only had the car a year and there's a little over 200 thousand miles on it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of reasons that might cause this but I'd start with the simple things.

#1 on my list would be an air leak.  Especially with a car this old there may be dry-rotted and/or cracked vacuum lines that are allowing air to enter the intake system where it should not.

#2 would be the throttle body and MAF sensor.  Check these, see if you can clean them, replace the MAF sensor.